Why does the macOS native Mail app no longer connect to Hotmail using valid username/password?
Strange situation. I can open a family members Hotmail through web but we fail to connect using the macOS Catalina (10.15.7) native Mail app.
Everywhere I look, the password should be the same as the Microsoft password.

I'm logged in using the web interface with the Microsoft password.
Trying an IMAP or POP3 connection however, I can't create a connection.

The assumption is that the native macOS app is also blocked by this.
Outlook.com (Hotmail) POP and IMAP is enabled
The login succeeded so I know the password is valid:

POP3 shows that the username or password is invalid:
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:995 -crlf --quiet
user xxx@hotmail.com
pass <Microsoft Password>

-> ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password


IMAP shows a failed login:
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -crlf --quiet
1 login xxx@hotmail.com <Microsoft Password>

-> NO LOGIN failed



Regular login is all but dead. If possible, you should use OAuth2. All modern mail clients support it. Alternatively, you might have to create an "app password".

@DanielB - "App passwords" may also be dead; I had to drop a mail client because I couldn't get it to talk to either GMail or Outlook.com with an app password, and the client was too old to support OAuth2.

IMAP is no longer the Microsoft supported way of connecting.
For recent macOS, in Apple Mail remove your IMAP/POP MS accounts and add a new one of type "Microsoft Exchange".
For older macOS, you may well have to just use the MS web interface.

This simply isn’t true. IMAP and POP3 very much remain supported. If you have other information, please provide some sources.

@DanielB - Correct, but it still appears to require login via OAuth2 rather than any of the 'traditional' methods.

Wether supported or not, changing to Exchange type fixed the issue.

@DanielB Using the connection method called IMAP in AppleMail no longer works (this may relate to OAuth2 not being available in Apple Mail IMAP). The MS described method is to use "Outlook.com" in iOS Mail and "Microsoft Exchange" in Mac Apple Mail. Scroll down in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-and-other-apps-are-unable-to-connect-to-outlook-com-when-using-basic-authentication-f4202ebf-89c6-4a8a-bec3-3d60cf7deaef#bkmk_add_account or https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-continue-to-use-apple-mail-on-a-macbook/7fcfe697-f056-4536-81bb-200528c238fa

Also the Exchange method is not working for me. I opens a dialog with a never ending spinner

It’s all about the framing. IMAP is still supported, period. Apple Mail may or may not support OAuth2. That doesn’t make IMAP unsupported. It makes Apple Mail an unsupported IMAP client for Outlook.com/Hotmail.

@DanielB - very much inclined to agree. So my tests with openssl s_client also suffered from the same then?

@DanielB I will take your word for it that MS is using IMAP with OAuth2. But this is not how it is presented by Apple Mail. I took this question as being about MS hotmail/outlook and Apple Mail.  For this Apple Mail's "Other Mail Account..." (IMAP/POP) method is not supported. The supported method is "MS Exchange".  Neither Apple nor MS talk about OAuth2. MS refers to "modern authentication" and Apple says nothing.  Can you post an answer that better describes how Apple Mail should used with outlook/hotmail?
